# How to get a value from json object?

Tags: java, json

```
{
  "address": [{
    "addressLine1": "Noida",
    "addressLine2": "UP"
  }],
}

{
      "address": [{
        "addressLine1": "Noida",
        "addressLine2": "UP"
      }],
    }

{
  "address": [{
    "addressLine1": "Noida",
    "addressLine2": "UP"
  }],
}
```

I have few different json objects in a json file.

I have a java code to read each adresses addressline 1.

I want to know is there a way to skip the second address and go to 3rd one to read addressline?

Comment: "I have a java code to read each adresses addressline 1.": so simply throw away the second one. You have to read the second address or you will not get to the third one.

Comment: Use a json parser like Gson, don't reinvent the wheel. You can make a class containing those attributes and parse it, then just refference the attribute you want.

Comment: How to throw the second one? this running through a for loop

Comment: I don't know if you tried it or not, and you aren't showing the java code you said you have to run all the elements. It is too broad. you can be using Json librarys or not. Please provide the code you have to get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you have fixed address list  you can do it like address[0].addressLine1,address[0].addressLine2 and address[2].addressLine1,address[2].addressLine2

Answer (score 0):

if u have fixed structure address list you can get the value like this :

```
alert ( objectJSON.address[0].addressLine1);
alert ( objectJSON.address[0].addressLine2);
alert ( objectJSON.address[2].addressLine1);
alert ( objectJSON.address[2].addressLine2);
```

please try

Comment: This does not look like Java. Java != JavaScript